# How to use a signed assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, .net-assembly, vspackage

**Scenario**

I have created a new Visual Studio Extension using the Extensibility templates. When creating the project this way, the assembly is already signed *(Assembly A)*.

I need to use another assembly *(Assembly B)* in this project. 
Assembly B also uses Assembly C
Since B and C are not signed, but A is signed I get this error:

> a strongly-named assembly is required

Now, I sign assembly B and C by `right click on the project name > Properties > Signing > Sign the assembly > new`.

When trying to use the functions of *Assembly B* in my main project *(Assembly A)* I get this run time error:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
>   qdex.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'MyAssemblyName, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=99d094e94ed4179f' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

**Question**

- Is there anything wrong with this scenario?
- What is the correct way to sign and use an assembly in another assembly?
- Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Are you able to sign all the assemblies with the same key, or are you saying Assembly A is already signed by someone else? I'm not saying that's the issue, but might be worth a try.

Comment: I've also tried signing all assemblies with the key that provided in my main project (A). Still getting the same error.

Comment: That exception does not have anything to do with signing.  Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems and read [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg590213%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Visual Studio 2015 the extensibility projects has been changed. (article is for VS 2010).